# JavaScript code doesn't add display: block to the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a wierd issue with Chrome / Safari when doing a "show more" feature.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    size_li = $("#grid .items .item").size();
        x=12;
    $('#grid .items .item:lt('+ x +')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
         x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
         $('#grid .items .item:lt('+ x +')').show();
    });
});
```

The full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/faL9ayLc) and works fine in Chrome on there but the exact same code doesn't work on my local pc or on a live server.

Firefox works fine, from looking at dev tools, the JavaScript isn't adding the `display: block` to the elements which is the following line:

```
$('#grid .items .item:lt('+x+')').show();
```

URL to see issue "live" - https://offtherailsmag.com/new (semi-risque images (lingerie etc.)

Any ideas to how to fix this?

Comment: could you be a little more specific than `doesn't work`

Comment: Do you know if the function is been called? If you put a `console.log` within your `ready` function does it fires when you load your website?

Comment: Take a look at the URL and my description - the image doesn't load although can see them in the source code, so for some reason the code isn't adding the "display:block" to the element

Comment: I see no difference between firefox and chrome - the show more button does nothing in either ... your question title says "weird error" ... what is the error? something in the developer tools console?

Comment: all solved, had an issue with the <script> tag around the code when I was looking at the JS code.

The see more link won't work as there is only one element added to the site so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
<script type="text/x-javascript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: how did I miss that? been looking at it for 2 hours :) thanks so much

Comment: i know that feeling :D